# Android Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to update  the latest dependencies

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
}
```

But when I am trying to update dependencies version from 
    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'`
to
    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

I am getting the error below:
Error: `"more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'"`

Comment: clean and rebuild project

Comment: I have tried this but still getting same error.

Comment: invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Are you sure you are not declaring it twice? Check the project structure

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and got the solution. 
The reason behind this is the use of old version of "com.android.tools.build:gradle".

Try 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

instead of 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.1'

in project level build.gradle file.